# Change css from sibling when hovered on with SCSS

Tags: css, sass

I want to change the css from the sibling when I hover on the element. Is there a way to do this with SCSS?

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/rqb5ytav/

Like when I hover on `.one` how do I change the background color of `.two`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`+` CSS selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp). It's available from CSS2.

```
.one:hover + .two {
    background-color:green;
}
```

Please look at the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rqb5ytav/1/.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Will mark you as answer in 3 min.

Answer (score 0):

You can use previousElementSibling and nextElementSibling property to get the css properties.

```
var divOneColor = null;
var divTwoColor = null;
$(document).on('mouseover', 'div', function(e) {
    var clName = $(e.target).attr('class')
if(clName == "one")  {
    divOneColor = $(this).css("background-color");
    divTwoColor = $(this.nextElementSibling).css("background-color");
    $(".two").css("background-color", divOneColor);
    $(".one").css("background-color", divTwoColor);
}
else if (clName=="two"){
    divOneColor = $(this.previousElementSibling).css("background-color");
    divTwoColor = $(this).css("background-color");
    $(".one").css("background-color", divTwoColor);
    $(".two").css("background-color", divOneColor);
}
```

});
Please look at the fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/7ow38dve/